# Relative text size in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontsize

I'm trying to design an academic poster for a conference. I have a very specific layout that I'd like to implement. Unfortunately, as this layout is bespoke, no templates will allow me to achieve this layout.

As a result of this, I decided it might be worth designing my own layout using TikZ. However, although I can design the schema, I'm having some issues with adding text. In particular, managing spaces within panels (e.g. `\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle`) such that text fits in the boxes. Basically, even though I have used the `\tiny` command, I can't make the text small enough.

Is there any way to shrink the text size even further? Perhaps such that it is relative to the size of the panel and always contained within the panel? I'm also interested in a solution to reducing the line space between lines of text.

Comment: A minimum working example would help the readers immensely to visualize your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`\fontsize{1pt}{1pt}\selectfont hello` is pretty small. 1st argument is the font size, second is the baseline skip

Comment: By default this won't produce smaller than `5pt`, see `ot1cmr.fd`

Comment: @AndrewSwann sorry didn't notice it was using `cm` for that font add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` then it will scale arbitrarily small, most other commonly used fonts are already specified to be scalable to any size.

Answer (score 3):

You can scale `node`s with the `scale` key. The middle one is `\tiny`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thin,every node/.append style={inner sep=0.2pt}]
\node[draw] {text};
\node[draw,font=\tiny] at (0,-1.2ex) {text};
\node[draw,font=\tiny,scale=0.1] at (0,-1.7ex) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```